# jQuery not working for the page included using jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to include a page using jQuery load function but then the page cannot access any jQuery script of the parent element. Can any one tell me how to get this working. Since I am  using blade template for Laravel, I am pasting my test code. However, this could be reproduced in any HTML-jQuery setup.

The problem in the below code is that when you click on the two divs in the test page, no function is called. (Basically it is not recognising jQuery in parent. It works if I paste the script code in the same page)

// page 1.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Mails</title>

{{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js') }}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css')}}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#testId").load("test")
$('.testClass').click(function(e) {
alert("test");
});
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   hj
    <div id="testId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

// test page (the page which is loaded)

```
<div class="testClass">test1</div>
<div class="testClass">test2</div?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#testId').on('click', '.testClass', function(e) {
    alert("test");
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot..! Marking this as the correct since you were first with the hint which almost solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#testId").load("test")
     $('.testClass').live('click', function(e) {
     alert("test");
});
 });
```

**Update**:
 sorry 
 the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

[courtesy](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

As per documentation what i did previously

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#testId").load("test")
         $('.testClass').on('click', function(e) {
         alert("test");
    });
     });
```

this function will attach handler to all elements containing 'testClass' class , however a delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element(as spookey suggested).

```
$( ".testclass" ).on( "click", ".testclass", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Ain't working buddy. I believe, what you meant was suggested by Spokey.

Comment: @ChintanParekh I actually suggested `.live` method then i realized it's depreciated after 1.7 version of jquery and i changed it , Yes spookey method is correct , and mine won't work as you are using above 1.7 version .Already +1 to spookey !